# Fixing Ionic Grid Layout

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ionic `-v1` for my app. This is my code for showing data in two side by side columns.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-50"  ng-repeat="news in mainCtrl.content.sources">
    <article class="item">
        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="{{news.url}}">
            <img ng-src="{{news.urlsToLogos.medium}}">
            <h2>{{news.name}}</h2>
            <p>{{news.description}}</p>
        </a>
    </article>
</div>
```

The problem is it is showing only two results. 
Can u please tell me y is that and how to fix this.?
And how can i use image-cards instead of article.?

Comment: what do you mean by it is showing only two results? How many entries are in there `mainCtrl.content.sources` array

Comment: more than 20 and not showing any errors though@sam

Comment: Try `<div class="col col-50"  ng-repeat="news in mainCtrl.content.sources track by $index">` . Also run ionic serve and see on browsers if those elements are not rendering on frontend due to html structure

Comment: Still not working .. @sam

Comment: can you show me your code in controller and make sure you have close all the tags properly in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

> i have use when two column display
>   [angular-masonry](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry)

the demo follow this [Link](https://masonry.desandro.com/)

if you implement then you can use image-cards instead of article

Your code something like that after implement the angular-masonry

```
<div masonry class="row">
 <div class="col col-50"  ng-repeat="news in mainCtrl.content.sources">
   <article class="item">
     <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="{{news.url}}">
        <img ng-src="{{news.urlsToLogos.medium}}">
        <h2>{{news.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{news.description}}</p>
     </a>
    </article>
</div>
```